# Is my approach to showing $(\exists y\in B\cap C)\Rightarrow(x\in A)$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary sets. Further, let $A$ be a subset of $X,$ and let $B,C$ be subsets of $Y.$ I am currently trying to prove a statement of the form
\begin{gather}
(\exists y\in B\cap C)\Rightarrow(x\in A).
\end{gather}
My approach to the problem is to prove the (equivalent) contrapositive statement, namely,
\begin{gather}
\neg(x\in A)\Rightarrow\neg(\exists y\in B\cap C),
\end{gather}
or, equivalently,
\begin{gather}
(x\notin A)\Rightarrow(\nexists y\in B\cap C).
\end{gather}
In order to show this last statement, I show two things:
\begin{gather}
\forall y\in Y,(((x\notin A)\wedge(y\in B))\Rightarrow(y\notin C))\\
\forall y\in Y,(((x\notin A)\wedge(y\in C))\Rightarrow(y\notin B)).
\end{gather}
Unfortunately, I’m not sure whether my approach to the problem is legit.

**Could you please help me see whether my approach is legal?**

Comment: In the last two formulas you write, what does $y\in B$ and $y\in C$ mean? Up to this point $y$ was quantified i.e. $\exists y$ etc. Here the quantifiers are gone and this holds no meaning because you have no specific $y$ you are working with. Do you mean to prefix the formulas with $\forall y$ or something like that? If so then this seems correct.

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment. When you say *prefix the formulas with $\forall y$ or something like that*, what do you exactly mean? Do you mean $(\forall y\in Y, ((x\notin A)\wedge(y\in B)))\Rightarrow (y\notin C)$? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: You need fully qualified formulae! No dangling $x$ etc. Or the question is meaningless.

Comment: Thank you both for your useful comments. I have now updated my original question accordingly. I hope now my question makes sense.

Comment: The way you write it now still has the same problem: you write it in the form $(\forall y: P(y))\to Q(y)$ and while $y$ is now defined on the left side, it still remains undefined on the right side. You're trying to say $\forall y (P(y)\to Q(y))$ instead. If you do this then your formulation will be equivalent to that which you are trying to prove.

Comment: I think I got you now? See the updated question.

Comment: Seems fine now.

Comment: P.S.: To whoever downvoted the question and voted to close it, which community guideline does my question fail to satisfy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or, equivalently, \begin{gather} (x\notin A)\Rightarrow(\nexists y\in
> B\cap C). \tag1\end{gather} In order to show this last statement, I show
> two things: \begin{gather} \forall y\in Y,(((x\notin A)\wedge(y\in
> B))\Rightarrow(y\notin C))\tag2\\ \forall y\in Y,(((x\notin A)\wedge(y\in
> C))\Rightarrow(y\notin B)). \tag3\end{gather}

Indeed, $$(1)\quad\equiv\quad(2)\land(3).$$ But $(1)$ needs to be rewritten as $$x∉A⇒\not\exists y\;y∈B∩C,$$ or, equivalently, $$x∉A⇒∀y\;y∉B∩C;$$ also, $(1),(2),(3)$ are not statements as they all contain a free variable $x.$

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary sets. Further, let $A$ be a subset of
> $X,$ and let $B,C$ be subsets of $Y.$ I am currently trying to prove a
> statement of the form \begin{gather} (\exists y\in B\cap C)\Rightarrow(x\in A). \end{gather}

Are you perhaps meaning to prove this instead? $$(\exists y{\in}Y\:y\in B\cap C)\Rightarrow(\exists x{\in}X \:x\in A)$$ Then we have
\begin{align}&\exists y{\in}Y\:y\in B\cap C\Rightarrow\exists x{\in}X \:x\in A\\
\equiv&\exists x{\in}X\;\forall y{\in}Y\;\big(y\in B\cap C\Rightarrow x\in A\big)\\
\equiv&\exists x{\in}X\;\forall y{\in}Y\;\big(y\not\in B\cap C\lor x\in A\big)\\
\equiv&\exists x{\in}X\;\forall y{\in}Y\;\big(y\not\in B\lor y\not\in C \lor x\in A\big).\tag#\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I don’t understand what you mean by “*free variable $x$*”. Also, I do not think that what I want to show is $(\exists y\in Y:y\in B\cap C)\Rightarrow(\exists x\in X:x\in A)$. In my real problem, $x$ is a specific object I define before the proof. Therefore, it’s not a matter of finding some $x\in X:x\in A$, but rather a matter of showing that my specific object $x$ belongs to $A$ (i.e., $x\in A$). Thus, I think that the statement is $(\exists y\in Y:y\in B\cap C)\Rightarrow(x\in A)$

Comment: @Héctor Sure, then remove all occurrences of $∃x{∈}X$ from the above answer, noting that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(\#).$

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much.